# libxslt compilation error: undefined reference to `xmlXPathContextSetCache'

Tags: compiler-errors, libxml2, libxslt

I am trying to install libxml and libxslt on my Linux machine. I already installed libxml2-2.7.8 in `/flocal/apps/libxml2-2.7.8`.

When I install libxslt-1.1.26, I get an error. This is the steps I followed while installing libxslt:

1. `sudo ./configure --with-libxml-prefix=/flocal/apps/libxml2-2.7.8 --with-libxml-include-prefix=/flocal/apps/libxml2-2.7.8/include --with-libxml-libs-prefix=/flocal/apps/libxml2-2.7.8/lib`
2. `sudo make` gives me the following error:

   > ../libxslt/.libs/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathCompiledEvalToBoolean'
   >
   > ../libxslt/.libs/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathContextSetCache'
   >
   > collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `perl`?